# Вывести все числа до 100 так что бы к тем числам которые простые была добавлена строчка

Tags: javascript, вывод, числа, условия

```
let n = 10;

nextPrime:
for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) { // Для всех i...
  for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) { // проверить, делится ли число..
    if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime; // не подходит, берём следующее, а если подходит то как выводим в консоль???!
  }

  alert( i ); // простое число
}
```

Comment: Какая строчка должна быть добавлена?.. Вывод в консоль - `console.log('Hello, world!')`

Comment: Если число простое то рядом с ним строчка что оно простое, если составное то ничего не выводить

Comment: Вам следует просто вместо `alert` поставить `console.log` с числом и строкой, которую хотите конкатенировать с этим числом

Comment: тут суть задачи вывести последовательно простые и составные числа, но к составным (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97) добавить пометку, что бы это выглядел как => (2-простое, 3 простое, 4 составное, 6 составное, 7 простое, 8 составное и тд ) выводить можно куда угодно в консоль и тд, главное сама формула как понять что число составное, если простое число вывожу в консоль число и рядом строчку простое и если составное то вывожу составное и так последовательно для каждого числа

Comment: Ух, ну если это уже все-таки окончательный вариант задания, то вам нужно расширить if-конструкцию второй инструкцией (перед `continue nextPrime`) - `console.log(`${i} составное`)`. В свою очередь, вместо `alert` должно быть что-то вроде `console.log(`${i} простое`)`. Не могу понять, что тут мудреного, - если этот код написали вы, то странно, как у вас не получилось додумать его буквально одним маленьким шагом

Comment: `let n = 100;

nextPrime:
for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) { 
  for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) { 
    if (i % j == 0) console.log(`${i} составное`); continue nextPrime; // 
  }

  console.log(`${i} простое`)
}` Я тоже так подумал сначала, но почему то все равно не работает, может я что то не так понял?

Comment: Если в if больше одной инструкции, их нужно заключать в фигурные скобки

Comment: Спасибо, наконец разобрался с этими скобочками, слава богу я не LISP изучаю